# C++ invalid operator< when using sorting

Tags: c++, string, sorting, operator-keyword

```
bool sortingGame(Player Player1, Player Player2)
{
    if (Player1.gamePercent() > Player2.gamePercent())// first compare precetage (float)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (Player2.gamePercent() > Player1.gamePercent())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (Player1.getLastName() > Player2.getLastName())//then names (std::string)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (Player2.getLastName() > Player1.getLastName())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (Player1.getFirstName() > Player2.getFirstName())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

heres in main():

sort(Players.begin(), Players.end(), sortingGame);

Here is the error showed when debugging in Visual Studio.

```
Program:C:\.....\include\algorithm
Line:3014
Expression: invalid operator<
```

Comment: And what line is 3014, exactly?

Comment: not sure... It's in #include <algorithm>

Comment: Are `Player1` and `Player2` in `main()` iterators?

Comment: @pinesfrst That Visual Studio error probably appears due to your `operator <` not being consistent, i.e. `a < b` but at the same time `b < a`.  Of course this is a nonsensical situation, but the Visual Studio's debug runtime tests for this erroneous condition, and maybe your code doesn't pass the test.

Comment: In addition, you should pass your objects to the function by `const reference`, not by value.

Comment: To get a definitive answer post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I mockup a players class and run your code it works fine. The error must belong somewhere else.

However your code could be tightened up considerably, by checking for equality and return the result of the comparison:

```
bool sortingGame(Player Player1, Player Player2)
{
    if (Player1.gamePercent() != Player2.gamePercent())// first compare precetage (float)
    {
        return Player1.gamePercent() > Player2.gamePercent();
    }
    else if (Player1.getLastName() != Player2.getLastName())
    {
        return Player1.getLastName() > Player2.getLastName();
    }
    else
    {
        return Player1.getFirstName() > Player2.getFirstName();
    }

}
```

Consider as well that strings are usually listed in reverse sort order(alphabetical).  Therefore the less than operator(<) would work better:

```
bool sortingGame(Player Player1, Player Player2)
{
    if (Player1.gamePercent() != Player2.gamePercent())// first compare precetage (float)
    {
        return Player1.gamePercent() > Player2.gamePercent();
    }
    else if (Player1.getLastName() != Player2.getLastName())
    {
        return Player1.getLastName() < Player2.getLastName();
    }
    else
    {
        return Player1.getFirstName() < Player2.getFirstName();
    }

}
```